# php: Why preg_replace_callback does not allow built in php functions, just anonymous user functions?

Tags: php, callback, callable, preg-replace-callback

This does not work, and outputs an empty string:

```
$check["pattern"] = "correct";
$text = "Could this be correct?";
echo preg_replace_callback($check["pattern"],ucfirst,$text);
```

Would have been nice to use built in functions. In fact general callbacks do allow built in functions as per http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php, but not preg_replace_callback. Could be a feature request for php?

Comment: I'm sure you've heard of `strpos` but I'm just putting it out there...

Comment: Does it also not work when you put "ucfirst" in quotes? (As it is a string...)

Comment: Yep thanks, this is just a dummy example. I am using a proper regex in real life for this :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should trigger a notice and a warning:

- Notice: Use of undefined constant ucfirst - assumed 'ucfirst'
- Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

If it doesn't, you seriously need to check your PHP error reporting settings. Fixing the code with the help of the error messages:

```
$check["pattern"] = "/correct/";
$text = "Could this be correct?";
echo preg_replace_callback($check["pattern"],'ucfirst',$text);
```

... we get this:

> Warning: ucfirst() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

So using a builtin callback function is working fine. However, as the [manual page for ucfirst()](http://php.net/ucfirst) explains, the function expects a `string`, not an array. And, as the [manual page for preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) explains:

> A callback that will be called and passed an **array** of matched elements in the subject string.

To sum up: it isn't a sensible feature request, it's a bug in your code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It works just fine with all functions. The problem is that those functions expect certain parameters. `ucfirst` expects strings as input, but `preg_replace_callback` is passing an array of matches.

So... if you have a built-in function whose signature is compatible with a `preg_replace` callback signature, it works. But no, not all built-in functions have a compatible signature.

Comment: Thanks, another good explanation. Alvaro was first, so I hope it is ok if I accept that :)